# Can I enable FIPS momentarily in a .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi, fips

Openssl allows going in and out of FIPS mode.  Does the windows crypto api and .net wrapper classes alow a similar function?

I want to enable FIPS mode, sign a document, and then return to normal mode.

Comment: Relevant https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2014/04/07/why-were-not-recommending-fips-mode-anymore/ not your answer, but it may guide your search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not; at least, not without some architectural changes.

You can enable/disable FIPS mode by setting a registry value:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled (DWORD)
```

0 is disabled, 1 is enabled

However, there are some limitations: once you load the cryptographic providers into your process, it "remembers" the state of that FIPS mode for the rest of the process' lifetime. So code like this would work:

(NOTE: both cases assume that FIPS mode is off at the beginning)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (RegistryKey fipsAlgorithmPolicy = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy", true))
    {
        fipsAlgorithmPolicy.SetValue("Enabled", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed(); // throws, which is what you want
}
```

But code like this would not:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed(); // Does not throw, which is expected
    using (RegistryKey fipsAlgorithmPolicy = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy", true))
    {
        fipsAlgorithmPolicy.SetValue("Enabled", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    sha = new SHA1Managed(); // Also does not throw, which is a shame
}
```

In order for your code to reflect the new state, you'd have to restart your process. With that being said, what you *could* do is sequester the code that performs the cryptographic routines into a "helper" process that your application spawns after setting FIPS mode. It'd be a bit of a pain to implement, but it would allow you to toggle FIPS mode and have your code behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Ended up using OpenSSL with openssl-net instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can on a per program basis - setting [enforceFIPSPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/enforcefipspolicy-element) to `true` in a .NET Runtime Settings Schema will specify that you want to enforce a computer configuration requirement that cryptographic algorithms must comply with the Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS).

Comment: That documentation appears to indicate that setting is `true` by default, and only acts to enforce FIPS-only mode if the registry key is already enabled; it's not a per-application version of that registry key.  Its true purpose appears to be that you can set it to `false` and the registry key setting that "enforces" FIPS-only mode will be ignored by the CLR, thus allowing that application to use non-FIPS-certified cryptographic providers.